# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_future_'

Tags: python, keras

What should I do solving this **print_function** eror in anaconda.

I write the below code,

```
from _future_ import print_function
```

But it show an error and that is,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-fd1a0773c2f5> in <module>
----> 1 from _future_ import print_function

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_future_'
```

**Note:** I uam using created environment as py36. because I it was to difficult to install ensorflow and keras where I used Python 3.7 . That's why I create new environment where python version is **Python 3.6.0** .

Comment: It's `__future__`, with two underscores on each side.

Comment: This particular future import is only needed for code intended to run under Python 2; the `print` statement was removed from Python 3.0.

Comment: If you're using Python 3.6, you don't need this particular import anyway - `print_function` has been the default since 3.0.  The line is only needed on 2.x versions.

Comment: Should I  avoid this statements in my code??

Answer (score 4):

There are two underscores on both sides of Python's `__future__` module, so your import should be:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```